# Is it possible to upload file on specific google drive in Android

Tags: android, drive

I have to developed a application such that any one can access my google drive and he/she can read and write file on my google drive using android.

Comment: Do you know about [**Firebase Storage**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/)?

Comment: yes I know the Firebase. But I dont want to used it.

Comment: ok. Then you can go for the links shared by @Nainal

Answer (score 1):

Kindly refer the link given below , You can use this for including google drive in your app.

https://github.com/googledrive/android-demos

https://developers.google.com/drive/android/